# Is it possible to include a javascript library file in a QML module in QT 4.8?

Tags: javascript, qml, pyside

We're building a set of applications in PySide using QML and QTQuick. Because we're using PySide we're limited to QML version 4.8.

I've built a set of components for use in our applications that we're sharing as a module between applications, this works great. By using defining a qmldir file and using QDeclarativeEngine.addImportPath we can load the module containing the components and reuse it between applications. This works great.

We also have a Style.js file that defines the theme we want to use for the applications. It simply defines a set of constants that we use for colors and

```
.pragma library

var background = "#afafaf"
var margins = 12
var textColor = "141436"
var textPointSize = 14
```

I can import this into QML files using

```
import Style.js as Style
```

and then use it like this

```
Button {
  color: Style.background
  ...
```

But I'd like to reuse it between applications too. I tried adding it to the module qmldir file

```
Style 1.0 style.js
```

and then importing it in qml files but this didn't work. Is there a way to reuse a js file this way?

Comment: Is it mandatory to have those parameters in a .js file? I mean, it would be feasible by exporting it from C++ to QML. In that case, I can provide you with a meaningful example from an application I've worked on.